# Findbugs contrib: Method throws alternative exception from catch block without history

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs

fb-contrib complains about

> Method throws alternative exception from catch block without history

in one of my try/catch blocks.

How can this be fixed ? Is there a detailed explanation about how to fix this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Original exception is caught, your code throws another exception without including the original in the `java.lang.Throwable cause`

Found something [here](https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/tags/violations-0.7.1/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/violations/types/findbugs/fb-contrib-3.4.2.messages.xml):

> This method catches an exception, and throws a different exception, without incorporating the 
>                   original exception. Doing so hides the original source of the exception making debugging and fixing
>                   these problems difficult. It is better to use the constructor of this new exception that takes an 
>                   original exception so that this detail can be passed along to the user.

Nice catch by FindBugs contrib !
So pass the cause, log it, ... do something with what you caught.
Hope this helps someone.

Example:

```
try {
  ...
} catch (final SomeException theOriginalCause) {
  // throw new SomeOtherException(); // Bad !
  throw new SomeOtherException(theOriginalCause); // Good.
}
```

Comment: A simple example of passing the cause (usually the best and easiest method) would nail this as a superb answer. I'd do it if I wasn't on my phone.

Comment: @DavidHarkness added example